# How to get reference of Component from projected content

Tags: angular, angular-content-projection

I am writing a common angular library component, where the consumers can pass on optional content/template/component through angular content projection mechanism. Below are some example classes to explain better.

#### The hierarchy tree:

**consuming-component** - projects **component-to-project** ----->

**common-container** - forwards projected content to it's child ------>

**common-item** - projected content renders here.

#### **Common Library:**

*component-to-project.component.ts -* this is the component that will finally render inside common-item and is projected from the consuming component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component-to-project',
  template: '<p>Projected Successfully!</p>',
})
export class ComponentToProjectComponent { … }
```

*common-container.component.ts -* This is the intermediate component that passes on the projected content to common-item.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'common-container',
  templateUrl: './common-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./common-container.component.scss'],
})
export class CommonContainerComponent {
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) projectedTemplateRef!: TemplateRef<any>;
(…)
}
```

*common-container.component.html*

```
...

<div>
    <common-item>
        <ng-template let-context>
            <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="projectedTemplateRef" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: context}">
            </ng-container>
        </ng-template>
    </common-item>
</div>
(…)
```

*common-item.component.ts* - This is where the projected content actually renders.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'common-item',
  templateUrl: './common-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./common-item.component.scss'],
})
export class CommonItemComponent {
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) projectedTemplateRef!: TemplateRef<any>;
    
    templateContext: MyContextData = { … };

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        // This is where I need the reference to the component passed through content projection.
        projectedComponent: ComponentToProject = // get component
    }
    (…)
}
```

*common-item.component.html*

```
(…)
<div>
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="projectedTemplateRef" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: templateContext}">
    </ng-container>
</div>
(…)
```

#### Consuming Application (Common Library is added as dependency)

consuming-app.component.html

```
(…)
<common-container>
    <ng-template let-context>
        <component-to-project (data)="context.data"></component-to-project>
    </ng-template>
</common-container>
(…)
```

I want the reference to the component-to-project component inside common-item component if this is what is being projected from consuming app.

I have tried few different approaches to get the projected component reference in the common-child component but got undefined in all cases.

- Added a reference (<component-to-project #myComponent>) to the projected component and resolve it using @ContentChild in common-item component

  ```
    @ContentChild('myComponent', { descendants: true }) 
     projectedComponent?: ComponentToProjectComponent;
  ```
- Resolve it using component class as selector of @ContentChild in common-item component

  ```
    @ContentChild(ComponentToProjectComponent, { descendants: true })
     projectedComponent?: ComponentToProjectComponent;
  ```
- Define an injection token for the component and use that injection token in @ContentChild to resolve.

  - component to project declaration module providers array

  ```
    { provide: TokenClass, useExisting: forwardRef(
      () => ComponentToProjectComponent).
  ```

  - common-child

  ```
    @ContentChild(TokenClass) projectedComponent?: 
    ComponentToProjectComponent;
  ```

However, none of the above approach worked.

Comment: Will watch this space.. I had a similar question but glad that someone has already posted it